# Nearby Connection API - device not advertising after disconnecting few times

Tags: android, google-nearby

I'm using so called Nearby Connections. One device is advertising (Nearby.Connections.startAdvertising() ) and another is discovering (Nearby.Connections.startDiscovery() ). This api works fine, I can successfully connect to the host device. However, if I disconnect, and reconnect few times, the device is not advertising any more. I'm calling Nearby.Connections.startAdvertising(), but onResult() method from PendingResult is not invoked at all. PendingResult is returned from Nearby.Connections.startAdvertising() method and you can use that to check if advertising started successfully. Did anyone have similar problem?

I have to reboot the device in order to advertising start working again. (reconnecting the wifi doesn't help).

Comment: Same problem here.  Nexus 6p stops returning the callback, success or not, what device did you have the issue with?

Comment: Any resolution on this? I'm facing the same situation... I use 0L for the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to not keep Advertising your connection if you don't need it.

I would suggest to use `stopAdvertising()` when you start your session, and when you need to reconnect just send the host `ConnectionRequest(...)` again without advertising.

and in any case you need it you can again switch it on.
if you want, you can try
`stopAdvertising()` and then `startAdvertising(...)` and see if it works because I am using this method and it's working perfectly.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

When you start advertising, do you set a timeout? You can try to set 0 there:

```
Nearby.Connections.startAdvertising(mGoogleApiClient, hostNameString, appMetadata, 0l, this);
```

In the nearby-connection quickstart example, you can set these two variables:

```
private static final long TIMEOUT_ADVERTISE = 0L;
private static final long TIMEOUT_DISCOVER = 0L;
```